# Trying to make it rain donuts using particles

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation

Im new to blender. 
have created a low poly version of the blender guru's donut. I linked it to a particle system that drops down on a collision plane in an attempt to make it rain donuts on my kids. 
problem is: the particles end up embedded halfway in the plane.
I tried to use size deflect but they stop midway in the air. 
also, they don't behave as rigid bodies. they don't topple over and most cases just stick up sideways un-naturally.
is it even possible to make particles behave as rigid bodies? 
I saw this older blender version tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G1ysjPeLKSQ&t=148s 
which appears to do just that.
here's the blend file: 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qofhga0gz0z2nq0/AAAno6xMNvYhfwMcKxPqWkZQa?dl=0
help would be most appreciated.

thnx

Comment: I think you should go with Rigid bodys and if there colission makes problems you can try to change the collision type to mesh and turn the samples up(under the rigid body world settings)

Comment: Ill try , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the expert, but I might be able to help...

I've had something like this, but not with doughnuts (unless that is why the cake... never mind). I would suggest some form of applying the particle system, prefferably somehow starting all the doughnuts in different positions mid-air. You may be able to randomize their positions with a script.